# Как разблокировать в LibreOffice (и также OpenOffice), кнопки F1 и F6, которые зарезервированы ерундой?

Tags: libre-office

F1 зарезервирована Справкой;
F6 зарезервирована Tab.
Как их раблокировать?
Одни эти команды способны нарушить совместимость с KeyMap схемой у других программируемых программ.

Comment: каким образом они могут что-то разрушить у других программ, если они работают только когда активно окно OO/LO?

Comment: Легко в прорамме А будет поставлено F1 на вырезание, в программу OL OO будет поставлено F2 на вырезание. В результате одинаковость протравлена, под справку.

Comment: А какая связь между одинаковостью и совместимостью?

Comment: Ну как обычно обхявляя понятие совместимость подразумевается способность быть пригодным, в результате в логике понятий  понятии совместимость может часто присутсоввовть условие: одинаковость.